# RowDetailsTemplate ItemSource Binded to an EF NavigationProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` of `Person` objects with another `DataGrid` in its `RowDetailsTemplate` which contains the selected person's Jobs, I am using `EntityFramework` to generate the `DataContext`, each person has a least one job (so Person contains a foreign key to another object of type `PersonWork`).
In order to populate the `RowDetails` `DataGrid` with the `selectedPerson's` works, I've bind its (the RowDetailsTemplate) `itemSource` to the navigation property of the `Person` class (generated by EF), but the `RowDetails` Grid is always empty! (when i inspect the `SelectedPerson.PersonWork` using the immediate window it contains records)

Here the `Xaml` Code i use:

```
<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ListPersons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson,Mode=TwoWay}"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PersonName}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PersonAge}" Header="Age" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="100"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <DataGrid Height="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson.PersonWorks}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WorkID}" Header="WorkID" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WorkTitle}" Header="Title" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WorkRecommandation}" Header="Recommandation" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="300"/>                              
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>   
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

And The Class Person generated by EF looks like so:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.PersonWorks = new HashSet<PersonWorks>();
    }

    public long PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public long PersonAge { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PersonWork> PersonWorks { get; set; }
}
```

Ps: I am using EF 6.1.1

**Update**
 The ListPersons is an `ObservableCollection`and it is instantiated like so :

```
var _dbContext=new DBEntities();
ListPersons= new ObservableCollection<Person>(_dbContext.Persons);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve that you must also specify the DataContext in inner DataGrid or get the inner DataGrid  Navigation property collection directly from the Main DataGrid using the ElementName, the following code work perfectly :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ListPersons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson,Mode=TwoWay}"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PersonName}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PersonAge}" Header="Age" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <DataGrid Height="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.PersonWorks, ElementName=DataGrid}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WorkID}" Header="WorkID" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="100"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WorkTitle}" Header="Title" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="100"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WorkRecommandation}" Header="Recommandation" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="300"/>                              
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>   
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```