# DataGrid SelectedItem not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So I am reallly confused here.

I created a datagrid, bound its itemsource two way and bound its selected item two way. The selected item getter gets called but the setter never does. All the pieces seem to be here. What am I missing?

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Properties ,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProperty ,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"  CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="LightBlue">

   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"  Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Units ,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUnit, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

My first datagrid works fine including the selected item.

The second third and fourth nested grids however don't bind to the selected item. The items sources work but that is it

```
   public class PropertyModel : ModelBase
   {
    private ObservableCollection<UnitModel> _Units;

    public ObservableCollection<UnitModel> Units
    {
        get { return _Units; }
        set { _Units = value; }
    }
    private UnitModel _SelectedUnit;

    public UnitModel SelectedUnit
    {
        get { return _SelectedUnit; }
        set { _SelectedUnit = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUnit"); }
    }
```

There are no binding expression errors or any other errors displayed in the output window.

Comment: I bypassed my problem with using two `ItemsControl` for my grid and some for the `RowHeader` and `ColumnHeader`. Still would be intressted if there is a way to do it with a `DataGrid`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to this is pretty obvious actually.

I forgot to put UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

so it should look like this

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Units ,Mode=TwoWay}" 
       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUnit,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
       CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

This solved the problem

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck on this for two days.

Comment: OMG this is so painful. I can put "SelectedItem="{Binding LoadOfRubbish" and it still compiles. Windows highlights the selected item but WPF makes me go through a stupid process to access it. Why, Why, Why, Why, Why?

Answer (score 1):

I faced something similar to that a couple of months ago, for some reason the inner `DataGrid` `ItemSource` wasn't set correctly using that way, i managed to fix that by binding using `ElementName` to set the RowDetail `DataGrid` `ItemSource` to the `SelectedItem` in the parent one :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Properties ,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProperty ,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"  CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="LightBlue">

   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"  Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Units ,Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=DataGrid}"
```

Comment: here what i told you about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131113/rowdetailstemplate-itemsource-binded-to-an-ef-navigationproperty

Comment: So this solution wont work and here is why. The problem isn't that the itemssource isn't populating. That works fine. The problem is that the property that the selected item for the nested grid is bound to isn't setting. I have tested your solution, including adding SelectedItem={Binding ElementName=PropertiesGrid, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay"} Clearly if I do this it might set the correct selected item but it destroys any attempt at binding it. The problem is somewhere else